# How to search a string for any number followed by a specific word?

Tags: python, regex

I have a paragraph that I've divided into lines and removed all punctuation. Now I want to check if any line contains any number, followed by the word "degrees", so I can output it.

For instance, on the sentence

`The temperature of the room was 32 degrees`

I want to find the substring

`32 degrees`

And on the sentence

`6 degrees of freedom in this rigid body`

I want to find the substring

`6 degrees`

Is there a way to consistently find the specific word, if it is preceded by any number?

Comment: You want regex.

Comment: @NGL123, edit the title of your question because, judging by the body of the OP, it doesn't match the question.

Comment: You should put in some example code too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on it:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 12 2019, 14:45:07) 
[GCC 9.1.1 20190605 (Red Hat 9.1.1-2)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> degree=re.compile(r'\d+\s*degree[s]?')
>>> s='32 degrees should be matched as 0 degree and 0degree should be as well, but not this last "degree" here.'
>>> degree.findall(s)
['32 degrees', '0 degree', '0degree']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex `r'\b\d+\s*degree[s]?\b'`

```
import re
s = '''32 degrees, 0 degree and 0degree should be matched 
       but not a56 degrees or 13 degreess'''
print(re.findall(r'\b\d+\s*degree[s]?\b', s))
```

Output

```
['32 degrees', '0 degree', '0degree']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex:

```
import re
FIND_DEGREES = re.compile(r'(\d+) degrees')
lines = [
  'The temperature of the room was 32 degrees'
]
for line in lines:
    match = FIND_DEGREES.search(line)
    if match:
        print(f'Temp: {match.group(1)} found in "{match.group(0)}"')
```

Output:

```
Temp: 32 found in "32 degrees"
```

Note if degrees appears more than once your should consider using `.findall` instead of `.search`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned use regex.

```py
import re

substring = re.compile(r"\d+\sdegrees")
for line in lines:
    print(substring.findall(line))
```

Comment: You need to replace ```\d*``` with ```\d+```. Using an asterisk will match ```degrees``` with no digits preceding it as well.